# Display current category name

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to display the name of the current category which I'm in. Nothing that I've been trying for 4 hours now has worked..

My code:

```
if($catList) {
    $c = 0;

    while($category = $catList->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $margintop = 38*$c;

        if($category['id'] == $thiscategory) {
            echo "<a href='".$link."&amp;category=".$category['id']."'>
                <div class='category_name'>".strip_tags($category['name']). "</div></a></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='".$link."&amp;category=".$category['id']."'>
                <div class='category_name'>".strip_tags($category['name']). "</div></a></div>";
        }
        $c++;
    }   
} else {
    echo "No categories to show.";
}
```

what I've tried to get the current category name, in a different area in the page:

```
if($category['id'] == $thiscategory) {
    echo ".strip_tags($category[name])." ;
}
```

which gives a blank result.

Comment: var_dump() both $category and $thiscategory to make sure that both are populated and that they contain what you expect

Comment: Did you check value inside `$category['id']` and `$thiscategory` variable ?

Comment: `$thiscategory` returns the category id, not the name. $category['id'] returns nothing.. empty result

Comment: I guess you use $category['id'] == $thiscategory condition for check current name. If so $thiscategory returns value but $category['id']  returns nothing. Then that condition will not true, so you better to check SQL query and the database table also.

Comment: are you sure you have id in your sql query? whats the current out put youa re getting from your code

Comment: Yes of course. There's actually a sidebar category which has all the categories' names fetched from the sql, so its there. and I'm getting no output at all.  $thiscategory displays the categ id tho.

Comment: `$c = 0;` and `38*$c` is 38 times 0 is always zero; basic math.

Comment: Do you know what this produces? `<a href='".$link."&amp;category=".$category['id']."'>` - I'll tell you; an invalid URL caused by `&amp;category`

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. Compare with $category (instead of $thiscategory), because you set in link &category=
2. You need to show some difference if value is selected

   ```
       if($catList) {
           $c = 0;

           while($myCategory = $catList->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
               $margintop = 38*$c;

               if($myCategory['id'] == $category) {
                   echo "<a href='".$link."&amp;category=".$myCategory['id']."' class=\"active\">
                       <div class='category_name'><strong>".strip_tags($myCategory['name']). "</strong></div></a></div>";
               } else {
                   echo "<a href='".$link."&amp;category=".$myCategory['id']."'>
                       <div class='category_name'>".strip_tags($myCategory['name']). "</div></a></div>";
               }
               $c++;
           }   
       } else {
           echo "No categories to show.";
       }
   ```

Comment: Please update your code to use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `strip_tags()`, to actually make this code secure. The former is the only function that actually protects against XSS, and propagating bad teachings is something I think we should try to avoid. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I don't want a "current" or "active" effect on the current category. Just trying to fetch its name for a different area in the page

Comment: U send $category and then set the $category to list. U lose your data. You can add first line $thiscategory = $_GET['category'];

Comment: @Liutas The problem here is all of their `&amp;category` which will produce an invalid URL and error reporting would have thrown them something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you may try **single_cat_title()**

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).